# how to read php param version of the file?

Tags: php, version, param

is there a way (a php function) to get the version 1.0.0.0 from a file?

```
/**
* @author softplaxa
* @copyright 2011 Company
* @version 1.0.0.0
*/
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a native php function that will extract the version 1.0.0.0 you listed, from a file. However, you can write one:

A. you can parse the file line by line and use preg_match()

B. you can used grep as a system call

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = file_get_contents("/the/php/file.php");
preg_match("/\*\s+@version\s+([0-9.]+)/mis", $matches, $string);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

You can probably write something way more efficient, but this gets the job done.

Comment: The `\/*` will not work on OPs example. I would avoid trying to match the comment block syntax alltogether. Checking for `@version` would suffice I guess.

Comment: true, updated the regex. I would probably just do an fopen and do a couple of fgets, if you see */ you've gone too far, if(strstr('@version', $line)) do the regex. Loads more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tested function that uses fgets, adapted from [Drupal Libraries API module](http://drupal.org/project/libraries):

```
/**
 * Returns param version of a file, or false if no version detected.
 * @param $path
 *  The path of the file to check.
 * @param $pattern
 *  A string containing a regular expression (PCRE) to match the
 *  file version. For example: '@version\s+([0-9a-zA-Z\.-]+)@'.
 */
function timeago_get_version($path, $pattern = '@version\s+([0-9a-zA-Z\.-]+)@') {
  $version = false;
  $file = fopen($path, 'r');
  if ($file) {
      while ($line = fgets($file)) {
        if (preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches)) {
          $version = $matches[1];
          break;
        }
      }
      fclose($file);
  }
  return $version;
}
```